# Drawing slope lines in a confined space

Tags: java, html-canvas

This isn't a game development question *per se*, but here goes...

I have a 50x50 pixel space in which I need to draw five lines: X and Y axes, and one line for each of a `steepest`, `average`, and `flattest` slope.

I'm working with (Java) code that was handed down to me with no documentation or commentary and I've never worked with drawing on a canvas before. Here's the code for a box that measured 175x75 px. This needs to be adapted for a 50x50 area as described above.

```
    DrawingArea canvas = new DrawingArea(175, 75);
    canvasContainer.add(canvas);
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 174, 75);
    canvas.add(rectangle);
    Line slopeMainLineX = new Line(5, 70, 170, 70);
    slopeMainLineX.setStrokeOpacity(0.5);
    canvas.add(slopeMainLineX);
    Line slopeMainLineY = new Line(40, 70, 40, 0);
    slopeMainLineY.setStrokeOpacity(0.5);
    canvas.add(slopeMainLineY);
    steepestLine = new Line(40, 70, 0, 0);
    steepestLine.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.add(steepestLine);
    avgSlopeLine = new Line(40, 70, 0, 0);
    avgSlopeLine.setStrokeWidth(2);
    canvas.add(avgSlopeLine);
    flattestLine = new Line(40, 70, 0, 0);
    flattestLine.setStrokeWidth(1);
    canvas.add(flattestLine);

    int steepestAngle = Math.round(site.getSlope().getMax());
    int averageAngle = Math.round(site.getSlope().getAvg());
    int flatestAngle = Math.round(site.getSlope().getMin());

    double xPointSteepestAngle = 40 + 120 * Math.cos(steepestAngle*0.0174532925);
    double yPointSteepestAngle = 70 + 120 * Math.sin(steepestAngle*0.0174532925);
    double xPointAverageAngle = 40 + 120 * Math.cos(averageAngle*0.0174532925);
    double yPointAverageAngle = 70 + 120 * Math.sin(averageAngle*0.0174532925);
    double xPointFlatestAngle = 40 + 120 * Math.cos(flatestAngle*0.0174532925);
    double yPointFlatestAngle = 70 + 120 * Math.sin(flatestAngle*0.0174532925);

    steepestLine.setX2((int) xPointSteepestAngle);
    steepestLine.setY2(70 - ((int) yPointSteepestAngle - 70));

    avgSlopeLine.setX2((int) xPointAverageAngle);
    avgSlopeLine.setY2(70 - ((int) yPointAverageAngle - 70));

    flatestLine.setX2((int) xPointFlatestAngle);
    flatestLine.setY2(70 - ((int) yPointFlatestAngle - 70));
```

I'm completely lost here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: too...many...magic..numbers..... *head explodes*

Comment: Off-topic and too localized. Did you try stackoverflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace some constants, it might help understanding what happens:

```
0.0174532925 => Math.PI / 180.0
175 => MyCanvas.width
75 => MyCanvas.height
174 => MyCanvas.width - 1
74 => MyCanvas.height - 1
5 => MyCanvas.padding
170 => MyCanvas.width - MyCanvas.padding
70 => MyCanvas.height - MyCanvas.padding
40 => (MyCanvas.height - MyCanvas.padding) / 2 + MyCanvas.padding
120 => MyCanvas.slopeLineLength /* About 40 */
```

Alternatively, to make the horizontal line centered, replace the following value:

```
40 => MyCanvas.height / 2 /* 37.5 in original, not 40.0 */
```

<s>Finally, you can calculate the slope line length instead of setting it (to about 50 if you don't want the lines to be too long):</s>

```
120 => Math.sqrt(
                   (MyCanvas.height / 2 - MyCanvas.padding)
                   * (MyCanvas.height / 2 - MyCanvas.padding)
                 + (MyCanvas.width - MyCanvas.padding * 2) 
                   * (MyCanvas.width - MyCanvas.padding * 2))
```

EDIT: Scratch the last part, obvious brain fart on my side. You should just pick a value between `(MyCanvas.height - 2 * MyCanvas.padding) / 2` and `(MyCanvas.width - 2 * MyCanvas.padding)` for `MyCanvas.slopeLineLength`.

Comment: +1 For replacing constants, pretty much can't go wrong there.